# Many model records in has_many-relationship columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, belongs-to

I have a `Brand` model and a `Price` model, thus:

**brand.rb**

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :a4_single, :a4_double, :a3_double, :two_a3_double
  has_many :prices, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**price.rb**

```
class Price < Brand
  attr_accessible :type, :quantity, :price, :brand_id
  belongs_to :brand
end
```

I want to be able to insert **multiple** `Price` records into **each** product column—i.e., say 10 `Price` records in `:a4_single`, eight in `:a4_double`, two in `:a3_double`, and say eight in `:two_a3_double`.

I'm only guessing that the `has_many` relationship defined above is correct, and I really don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't proceed any further.

Do something like this

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brand_prices
  has_many :prices, :through => :brand_prices
  attr_accessible :name
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brand_prices
  has_many :brands, :through => :brand_prices
  attr_accessible :price, :quantity, :type
end

class BrandPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :price
end
```

Comment: This solution makes sense, but it leaves me wondering a few things: I've nested the forms/models, and set up a `has_many, :through` relationship between them. Firstly, how would I associate the `Price` instance with a particular `Brand` column? I thought of making a `Brand.column_name.each` `collection_select` thing, but that seems certifiably un-Rails. Secondly, saving the pricing information works, but the `edit` screen shows no values despite them being stored in the database. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've been thinking about this the wrong way, but you definitely helped me get to the solution. I was doubling the `Brand` column information in another model. Crisis over. And thanks kindly.